# How come these DIVs will not display on the same line?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="left_side">LEFT</div>
    <div id="center_s">CENTER</div>
    <div id="right_side">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

...and CSS:

```
#root {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left_side {
    float: left;
}

#center_s {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 65px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#right_side {
    float: right;
}
```

However, I get the following:

[image: Screenshot]

The DIV on the right is on a separate line, which is **not** what I want. How can I make it stay on the same line as the other DIVs?

**Note:** you can see a live demo and play around with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/UDb4D/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because your `#center_s` div expands to the width of the remaining line. If you put `#right_side` above `#center_s` in the HTML order, it'll work fine.

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UDb4D/2/

Comment: Thank you - not only for finding the problem, but explaining why it occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Because the center has no float and right-floated elements need to appear first. Add `float: left;` to your `#center_s` or move the `#right_side` div before so it looks like this:

```
#root {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left_side {
    float: left;
}

#center_s {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 65px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    float: left;
}

#right_side {
    float: right;
}

<div id="root">
    <div id="right_side">RIGHT</div>
    <div id="left_side">LEFT</div>
    <div id="center_s">CENTER</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: If `#right_side` is before `#center_s` you don't need to float `#center_s`

Comment: @Archonix - tru dat. it should say `or`.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly hacked this up. Bare in mind that I'm a developer, not a web designer.

```
<div id="root" align="center">
    <div id="right_side">RIGHT</div>
    <div id="center_s">CENTER</div>
    <div id="left_side">LEFT</div>
</div>
```

And...

```
#root {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left_side {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#center_s {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 65px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#right_side {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite have the same effect because `margin:auto` doesn't work the same way on inline elements. See my method below.