# css-how to set a three parallel DIV?

Tags: css, html

how to set three div arranged horizontally like this?
The left one width:150px, the right one width:150px, the center one width are the rest of the pixels, and the center one min-width will be 800px. All the div need a position:relative. 
Thanks.

Comment: do you have any requirements to use div's ,in general DIVS are advised to use. But if your case is simple tables might be the fast and easy to create three column or four column.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116085/how-come-these-divs-will-not-display-on-the-same-line/4116103#4116103

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we go, html is below:

```
<div id="wrap">

   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="center"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>

   <div class="clearBoth"></div>

</div>
```

and now css below:

```
#wrap {
width: auto;
position: relative;
}

.left, .right {
width: 150px; //or use 30%
float: left;
}

.center {
float: left;
min-width: 800px; //or use 60%
width: auto;
position: relative;
}

.clearBoth {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a newer, I can not vote 'this answer is helpful' for you all.

Answer (score 3):

Use a wrap if you want to define a fixed maximum width.

```
.wrap {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:1200px; /* Optional */
}

.left {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
}

.middle {
  float:left;
  min-width:800px;
}

.right {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
}

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't forget the width:800px; for .middle{}

Comment: Ah right, forgot he mentioned the min-width.  Added that in there.

Comment: Thanks, in this case, is the wrap allow to set a percent?      .wrap { 
  overflow:hidden; 
  width:100%; /* Optional */ 
}

Comment: Yes that should work if you want it to extend the width of their browser window.

Comment: If you move the `<div class="right">Right</div>` before `<div class="middle">Middle</div>` and set `.right` to `float: right;` as well as remove the `float` from `.middle` it works as well.

Comment: Right, I've found there are several different ways to make it work.  Fortunately this is one of the easiest CSS things to make the same across all browsers.  (IE I'm looking at you!)

Comment: Thank, Now I know it well. :}